# Application crashes on start when running through remote desktop

Tags: wpf, permissions, remote-desktop

I am developing a WPF application. I am accessing an admin account on a clients machine using remote desktop. When I try to run the application I am getting a xaml parse exception when the program attempts to initialise.

The strange thing is if I run the program without remote desktop on the same account it works fine.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: On the same account or on the same computer when you are talking about running without remote desktop?

Comment: Do you have any graphics intensive stuff going on?  I have the same problem when I use OpenGL over remote desktop.

Comment: This bug report may be relevant:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1930838/animated-wpf-effects-cause-hard-crash-over-rdp-under-certain-conditions